# iOS Firebase Crash Reporting - Error running build script

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I get the following error when running the script to upload symbol files (everytime I try and build my project):

> upload-sym-util.bash:351: error: symbolFileUploadLocation: The API Key and the authentication
>   credential are from different projects.

Here is my build script:

```
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
    GOOGLE_APP_ID=<app-id>
    "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/<app>/Firebase/CrashReportingKey-Dev.json
else
    GOOGLE_APP_ID=<app-id>
    "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/<app>/Firebase/CrashReportingKey.json
fi
```

Things I've done/checked:

1. The `GOOGLE_APP_ID` and `CrashReportingKey*.json` are associated with the same project.
2. My `GoogleService-Info*.plist` files have the `API_KEY` field.
3. Checking "Run script only when installing" box, which allows me to run the app, but doesn't actually run the script in a development environment. So crashes are sent to Firebase, but they aren't symbolicated.

I'm open to any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to delete the GoogleService-Info*.plist and then download and install it again?

Comment: I'm going through exactly the same issue right now.

Comment: @i6x86 I didn't "reinstall" them, but I did download them again and verified that they are the same as the ones in my project.

Comment: Had you been able to upload symbols for this same project in the past?  Does the problem still persist today?

Comment: @DougStevenson This is the first time I've tried to add Firebase Crash Reporting to any project. I haven't had the chance to try again since I created this question, but nothing has changed that I'm aware of so I imagine it would still happen.

Comment: I'm asking because it might be a temporary problem at the server.  This is the first time I've ever seen this error, and that particular message isn't generated by the client.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, this still happens.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hey Doug, just letting you know I've had the same problem since setting up multiple app environments / firebase projects within the same Xcode project. I have a similar build script to the one in the question.

Comment: @PatrickGoley Does the accepted answer below address your situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that there's no way to override the GoogleService-Info.plist. However there's still a way to override the pieces of information the upload script uses from that file.

1. Open the GoogleService-Info.plist corresponding to the .json.
2. Search for GOOGLE_APP_ID and API_KEY.
3. Adjust the build script like so:

   ```
   export FIREBASE_APP_ID=<GOOGLE_APP_ID>
   export FIREBASE_API_KEY=<API_KEY>

   "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "ServiceAccount.json"
   ```

In your case, your final script should look something like:

```
    if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]; then
        export FIREBASE_APP_ID=<app-id>
        export FIREBASE_API_KEY=<API_KEY for dev>
        "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/<app>/Firebase/CrashReportingKey-Dev.json
    else
        export FIREBASE_APP_ID=<app-id>
        export FIREBASE_API_KEY=<API_KEY for release>
        "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/<app>/Firebase/CrashReportingKey.json
    fi
```

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer as it actually solves the problem in the question. My answer doesn't allow for two crash environments.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved :

in terminal :
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*

Xcode :
Product -> Clean

Comment: Thanks for this little tip. I added the rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload* to the build script so I can actually support multiple Firebase accounts.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with the name of `GoogleService-Info.plist` file.

In my project, I had the following files:

- `GoogleService-Info.plist`
- `GoogleService-Info-Dev.plist`
- `CrashReportingKey.json`
- `CrashReportingKey-Dev.json`

Firebase Crash Reporting upload script always looks for a file named `GoogleService-Info.plist` exactly. Since it found one, and I was telling the script to use `CrashReportingKey-Dev.json`, it threw the project mismatch error.

From my research, there is no way to tell the Firebase Crash Reporting upload script which `*Info.plist` file you want to use, so I have decided to only upload symbol files for release builds, which is fine.

My run script is now the following, and works as it should.

```
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]; then
    GOOGLE_APP_ID=<app-id>
    "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}"/<app>/Firebase/CrashReportingKey.json
fi
```

I then removed `CrashReportingKey-Dev.json` from my project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to reset my OAuth credentials by running this command :
rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*

as described here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios

Works fine for me now !

Comment: Where did you run that? In terminal or build phase?

Answer (score 0):

I have this error today.
And I found this config, simply replace this GOOGLE_APP_ID with the value in your GoogleService-Info.plist

View image here, sorry I don't have permission to post image
[Replace GOOGLE_APP_ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YY5I.png)