# Multiple firebase apps, crash reporting configuration issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have configured multiple firebase databases in my single iOS app.

[image: xcode screen shot]

here is the code in my AppDelegate, that selects which firebase db I have to choose at run-time

```
func initFirebase(){

        // Check the Flag which Firebase to connect with
        if (UserDefaultsManager().getFirebaseConfiguration()){

            let resource = UserDefaultsManager.env_firebase?.value(forKey: "resource") as! String
            print("resource \(resource)")
            let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType:"plist")
            let options = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile:filePath!)
            FirebaseApp.configure(options: options!)

        }
    }
```

This is all working fine.

Issue is with crash reporting, I have to make the firebase crash reporting dynamic too.

Right now I have configured my firebase crash reporting with `jBackend-genetech-dev-crash-reporting.json` , here is my crash reporting shell script.

```
# Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist (its my genetech-dev firebase service account actually) file
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:740631780656:ios:ddccc74c2f726b3a


# Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}/JamesApp/jBackend-genetech-dev-crash-reporting.json"
```

So When I connect my app to the firebase db with configuration defined in service account `GoogleService-Info.plist` its working flawlessly i.e I am getting the crash reports with the exact line number of the crash. here is the screenshot.

[image: crash reporting OK]

But whenever I connect with other firebase accounts example `GoogleService-Info-mh6-prod.plist`, I am getting the crash reports in this case too but with `no Line number`, see screenshot below.

[image: crash reporting NOK]

**More Info**

Am I testing on real device? Yes

Is bitcode support disabled in my project? Yes

**Question:**

How to make my crash reporting script dynamic in my case.
I have seen this [iOS Firebase Crash Reporting - Error running build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732390/ios-firebase-crash-reporting-error-running-build-script) , i.e making the script dynamic depending upon the app configuration variable i.e release/debug. but my scenario is different, my app select the firebase database depending on the app's System settings bundle. seen screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure - if you're dynamically selecting from multiple projects, you also have to make sure all those projects have symbols uploaded to them so they can be interpreted in the console.

Comment: @DougStevenson how to do that. I don't have any idea whats symbols are all about. please share any link. thanks

Comment: @DougStevenson if you are talking about this https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files its already done in my project. I have shared the script above.

Comment: Yes, what I'm asking is if you've uploaded your symbols to ALL of your projects, not just one.

Comment: Do I have to do this manually something? I am assuming is that the above script will upload my symbol files automatically when this script runs. isn't it?

Comment: That script will upload to *one* project.  You need to modify things so it uploads to *all* projects.

Comment: Yeah. thats the actual question my dear :) how to this.

Comment: Change the script to upload to all the projects.  It does one, now change it to do as many as you need.

Comment: You mean I copy past the above script 4 time (If i have 4 firebase databases)? and replace the google app-id and google crash service account file accordingly? isn't it?

Comment: One script with 4 uploads, or 4 scripts with one upload each, it doesn't matter. Whatever you want.

Comment: Okay. will try this. let you update. thanks :)